# Changing global variables in functions

Tags: c++, function, variables, global, local

I'm learning c++ with the book 'Course beginning c++ through game development'.

When i'm declaring a global variable, this global variable is not changable. When im declaring a local variable in a function it's supposed to simply hide the global one. The problem is, it seems that i'm changing the global variable when declaring the local variable in a function. The following code will help me explain:

```
//the code
// ConsoleApplication64.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console     application.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int glob = 10; //The global variable named glob
void access_global();
void hide_global();
void change_global();

int main()
{
cout << "In main glob is: " << glob << endl;
access_global();

cout << "In main glob is: " << glob << endl;
hide_global();

cout << "In main glob is: " << glob << endl;
change_global();
cout << "In main glob is: " << glob << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}

void access_global(){
cout << "In access global is: " << glob << endl;
}

void hide_global(){
glob = 0;
cout << "In hide global is: " << glob << endl;
}

void change_global(){
glob = 5;
cout << "In change global is: " << glob << endl;
}
```

When I cout glob for the first time in int main it has the global value, 10. Then i cout the glob in a function and it seems to work properly, 5. Then i want to cout glob in main again, only to find out the value has changed from the global, 10, to the local 5. Why is this? According to the book, this is not supposed to happen. I work in Microsoft visual studio 2010.

Comment: There are no local variables in this code. Read more carefully about declarations.

Comment: Where do you think you're declaring a local variable? There's only one variable declaration here, and that's global. All `hide_global` does is change its value. Perhaps that should hide it with a local declaration: `int glob = 0;`

Comment: _"I'm learning c++ ... When i'm declaring a global variable..."_ - Stop!

Comment: `When im declaring a local variable in a function it's supposed to simply hide the global one.`   Seriously, what are you really trying to accomplish?   If you're trying to mimic how another computer language does things, stop doing that.

Comment: @Component10 Come on... part of learning C++ is understanding the rules around namespace scoped variables. This clearly isn't code in a real project.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What does this have to do with other languages? He's just learning about a particular concept in C++.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Yes, you are right, though my comment wasn't intended to be taken too seriously. Hopefully as well as an understanding  of the scoping rules of global variables, the OP may gain an appreciation of why they can also be problematic.

Comment: @molbdnilo You are comletely right. I didn't even declare a local var, i just changed the global one. Ty!

Comment: @Component10 I'm just learning this stuff bro. But now i'm pretty interested. Why shouldn't i declare global variables ever?

Comment: @JosephMansfield This is my first language ever. Haha. I can only wish i knew how to program python.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It was just a test to learn about the global and local variables. But many programming languages overlap in use don't they? Why are you so against the example i gave you?

Comment: @Stephen [Why is global state so evil?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/148108/80257) Global variables are a form of global state.

Comment: @Stephen `It was just a test to learn about the global and local variables`  My experience is that a lot of these "tests to learn" lead to the programmer actually using such "tests" in real code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ah i see. If i would start a project now, i would probably use code like the example. I know too little to do otherwise. But i'll make sure to learn from my mistakes :)

Comment: @Stephen I think others have answered your question on why globals might be a problem. They are sometimes necessary but as a general rule, the tighter you can keep the scope of your variables, the more readable your code will be, the less bugs you'll have and the more testable and maintainable your code will be ... and global scope is as loose as you can get. Happy coding.

Answer (score 5):

The code:

```
void hide_global(){
glob = 0;
cout << "In hide global is: " << glob << endl;
}
```

Is not declaring any new variables, it is assigning to an *already existing* variable called `glob`, which is your global variable. To declare a new variable in the function you would need to specifiy the data type as well, like this:

```
void hide_global(){
int glob = 0;
cout << "In hide global is: " << glob << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not creating a local variable in any your `hide_global` function, you are simply changing the global variable. To create a new local version, do this:

```
void hide_global(){
    int glob = 0; //note the inclusion of the type to declare a new variable
    cout << "In hide global is: " << glob << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void hide_global(){
  glob = 0;
  cout << "In hide global is: " << glob << endl;
}
```

You're not hiding the global variable here at all. You're just assigning `0` to the global variable. In fact, it's exactly the same as your `change_global` function - so why would you expect it to behave any differently?

To hide a variable, you need to *declare* a new variable. A variable declaration consists of a type, a name, and an optional initialiser. For your code, it would look like so:

```
void hide_global(){
  int glob = 0;
  cout << "In hide global is: " << glob << endl;
}
```